# How can I know whether the user type title in Arabic or in English?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a page taps with title that entered by user. How can I know wither the user type title in Arabic or in English (in the view port)?

```
<div class="page-tabs tabs">
<div *ngFor="let page of pages">
<div *ngIf="inRange(page)" class="tab" [class.active]="page == 
selectedPage" (click)="onSelectPage(page)">
  <div class="title" [innerHTML]="page.title | englishMarker"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here the div with class title is the place where title will be after writes by user - how can I determine wither user type title in Arabic or English?

I want to determine that in html or Typescript

Answer (score 3):

you could match characters A-Za-z for english and ب to ى‎ for arabic
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode#Contextual_forms here are arabic unicode characters and their variations

Comment: Seems to be the most logical solution. May not work if user enters text containing both character sets, but that scenario would be problematic anyway.